# neo4j - create different user authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, neo4j

i am new to neo4j. 
Can anyone tell me how to create different users

`(say user1 and user2)` with different authentication for database access like user1 can write to database but user2 can only read from database .. i have read the documentation but could not figure it out... 
    i am using `neo4j 2.0 with rest api from jquery and cypher`.

i would be great if the process is properly explained..
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j does not use user authentication by default. There is a detailed section in the reference manual covering [security topics](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html).

Additionally there's a add-on [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension/tree/2.0).

Comment: thank you stefan but i have seen these docs but could not understand it. Is there another doc or implementation example which i can read